# How did this bogus entry sneak into my apt sources?

Tags: apt

A while ago, I decided to try dropbox. Since I could `apt-get` it, I thought it was free software.

However, I quickly discovered that the `apt-get` command only downloaded a *downloader* for dropbox daemon.

So I stopped that dead in its tracks, did an `apt-get remove`, aaaand...

wait a second.

The repository won't go away! In fact, if I `apt-get update`, it's still in there:

```
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com wheezy InRelease
```

It's not in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so how did it get there?

Comment: For the future: `apt-get install etckeeper`, pick your favorite version control software, and `etckeeper init`. This way your `/etc` is automatically under version control, and you can easily find out when this appeared, and from there why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most probably a file located inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is used by several third-party applications to allow automatic updates without having to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list`. It seems to have been added with apt *0.6.43* in 2005.

Comment: yes. it was a file called dropbox.list inside of that directory.